# Faced the issue: Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::links does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

Hey everyone I was creating a laravel project and I wanted to add the pagination but I faced this error :

> Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::links does not exist. (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\TestingTask\resources\views\income\index.blade.php)

Here is the controller code:

```
public function index()
    {

        $income =Income::orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate(1);
        return view('income.index', compact('income'));

    }
```

The view code:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<h3>Profit</h3>
<br>
@if(count($income)>0)
@foreach($income as $income)
    <div class="card bg-muted">
    <h3><a href="/income/{{$income->id}}">{{$income->title}}</a></h3>
    </div>
@endforeach
    {{$income->links()}}
@else
<p>No result</p>

@endif
@stop
```

Comment: Can you change your foreach variable to `foreach($income as $single_income)`

Comment: @AyazShah, yes Ayaz you were right I changed and all worked perfectly:)

Comment: Sure I have also added an answer kindly check it. It may useful for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your code. change `$income` to `$inc`.

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<h3>Profit</h3>
<br>
@if(count($income)>0)
@foreach($income as $inc)
    <div class="card bg-muted">
    <h3><a href="/income/{{$inc->id}}">{{$inc->title}}</a></h3>
    </div>
@endforeach
    {{$income->links()}}
@else
<p>No result</p>

@endif
@stop
```

Comment: you are right I have changed and all worked perfectly:). But can you explain why it worked ok until I used {{$income->links()}} even if I had foreach($income as $income).

Comment: @Mirasan $income refers to array of collection when we use it in foreach loop it starts refferring to single object that's why it was not working before

Answer (score 0):

This is because of your foreach loop variable kindly change as following

```
@if(count($income)>0)
@foreach($income as $income_single)
...
@endforeach
    {{$income->links()}}
@else
```